# iOS Safari Selection Desable Copy / Define / Share.. link

Tags: ios, css, angularjs, cordova, webview

We have created a cordova App using angular JS, and in the app we have desabled the Apple webview copy/share/define menu from our view code in Xcode. This works as intended, since we don't want the menu to popup.

The angular JS code is also hosted on a website, where desktops can access it, but here the Copy/share/define menu is shown.

I have tried numerous things I found on Stackoverflow and other website, most of them give the following css tag:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

This competly desabled selection, we just want the copy/define/share menu gone, is this possible, ore is this something that has yet to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `ng-hide="true"` attribute on the menu so that it will be hidden on the view.

Comment: Thank you for your response :). Where can I add this code? As far as I know I do not have any control over the Apple share menu.